# open app when screen on

Tags: android, lockscreen

i'm trying to get my app started when the screen is on. It is a LockScreen so it should show up everytime the screen goes on. The following code is what I wrote so far and I'm not sure what is wrong. There is no error message. The application just runs normally but won't start when the screen goes on.

This is my Receiver:

```
package com.example.screenlocker;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


public static boolean screenOff = true;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        screenOff = true;
        Intent i = new Intent(context,LockService.class);
        i.putExtra("screen_state", screenOff);
        context.startService(i);



    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        screenOff = false;
    }
}
```

and this my Service:

```
package com.example.screenlocker;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class LockService extends Service {

public void onCreate(){
    IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    BroadcastReceiver locker=new StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver();
    registerReceiver(locker, filter);
}

  @Override
  public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
      boolean screenOn = intent.getBooleanExtra("screen_state", false);        
      if(screenOn){
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));  

               }

  }

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

Maybe you know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You gave your if expression wrong if i see correctly.

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
    screenOff = true;
    Intent i = new Intent(context,LockService.class);
    i.putExtra("screen_state", screenOff);
    context.startService(i);



}
```

You set screenOff = true when it comes ON. Switch it to false and bellow in `Action_SCREEN_OFF` to true.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer but it still doesn't work. I heard of starting the service in foreground but I'm not sure if it would help and how it works.